# PageRank with custom initial scores

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory, social-networking, pagerank

I am trying to implement a simple algorithm that will calculate PageRank on a directed network generated and handled with NetworkX. However, I'd like to add a simple change: rather than having the initial PageRank for each node be equal to 1/n, where n is the number of nodes in the graph, I want each node to have rank 1.

So far I have tried checking out the official documentations on PageRank, but I found nothing that seems to help. Apparently the 'personalization' parameter is of no use either. I tried using nstart, but to no avail. The code currently looks like this:

```
import networkx as nx

D=nx.DiGraph()
D.add_weighted_edges_from([('1','2',0.5),('1','3',0.5)])
nst = {n: 1 for n in D.nodes}

print(nx.pagerank(D, alpha = 0.95, nstart=nst))
```

At the moment, the ranks given to each node at the end of the calculation still sum up to 1, while they should sum up to 3.

Is such a thing even feasible to begin with? Should I look elsewhere to implement such an algorithm? Could there be problems with convergence if such a change is applied? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[PageRank](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html) in networkx has an attribute **nstart**:

> **nstart** (dictionary, optional) – Starting value of PageRank iteration for each node.

Here is source code for this:

> ```
>     # Choose fixed starting vector if not given
>     if nstart is None:
>         x = dict.fromkeys(W, 1.0 / N)
>     else:
>         # Normalized nstart vector
>         s = float(sum(nstart.values()))
>         x = dict((k, v / s) for k, v in nstart.items())
> ```

You can just specify **nstart** in your code, like this:

```
nst = {n: 1 for n in G.nodes}
pr = nx.pagerank(G, nstart=nst)
```

---

**Edit 1:** Modern PageRank algorithm forcefully [normalizes start vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Computation) (you can see it in the code above). The whole algorithm is based on it and if one will force **nstart** values to be `1`, not `1/N`, it will be broken because convergence:

[image]

will never be assumed (`e` is increasing each iteration). If you want to use `1` as starting values, as in the original PageRank algorithm:

> In the original form of PageRank, the sum of PageRank over all pages was the total number of pages on the web at that time, so each page in this example would have an initial value of 1.

You should implement the whole algorithm manually because it is deprecated.

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will accept/upvote it.

Comment: I am still struggling with the toy code I am using. I provided an example in the my question, which I have edited. I also did upvote your answer, but my reputation is apparently too low to do that.

Comment: Did you really add it? I don't see anything new in question.

Comment: Just added! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @vurmux I have a similar question in pagerank that I thought that you know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246401/what-is-personalisation-parameter-in-pagerank-in-networkx Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thank you.